# Coverage for a particular jar inside war/ear file

Tags: java, maven, code-coverage, jacoco

I am using this-
http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/examples/java/ReportGenerator.java

to calculate the code coverage using jacoco.

It simply takes the jar/class/ear etc files and then generates report.

Please let me know, how do I calculate if I just want to do for a particular jar inside an ear file?

Comment: by going to that project who's generating that .jar and running gradle build or gradle xxxxxTest task and then running gradle jacocoTestReport. Otherwise, you have to provide the source code of that .jar and tell Gradle where to look for that .jar actual source code for main(java) while runing tests.